# show results of JavaScript after function complete

Tags: javascript, html

**Situation**

 the script below changes the table layout. However, due to the large amount of data, there is a few seconds where I can see a squashed table.

**Question**
How to display the table after it has run the JavaScript or ready.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/96/) This fiddle has a small amount of data, so it doesn't show the above issue.

**inside HTML**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="settable.js"></script>
</head>
```

**JavaScript**
*actual amount of data consists of 800~1000 rows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tbody = "#table-body";
    var row = $("#table-body tbody>tr");

    $("<div>", {
        class: "tablewrapper"
    }).insertBefore(tbody);
    $("<table>", {
        class: "header"
    }).appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "headerwrapper"
    }).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
    $(tbody).appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "bodywrapper"
    }).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
    $(tbody + ">thead").clone().val("").appendTo("table.header");
    $("table.header>tr").removeClass("header_hidden");
    $(tbody).find("thead th").empty();
    $(tbody).find("tbody td:nth-child(3)").addClass("lefty");
    $("<input>", {
        type: "text"
    }).attr("id", "search-criteria").appendTo($("<div>", {
        class: "s_box"
    }).insertAfter("div.bodywrapper"));
    $("<div>").attr("id", "count").appendTo("div.s_box");

    resizeTable();
    //var bodyTd = $("#table-body tr td");

    $(window).resize(resizeTable);

    //search function
    $("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
        var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
            return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
        }).toLowerCase();
        //var row = $("#table-body tbody>tr");

        if (keyword !== "") {
            row.each(function () {

                var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                //shorthand if function
                $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            });
            var srowCount = row.filter(":visible").length;
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
            rowCount();
        } else {
            $("tr.s_empty").remove();
            row.show();
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = row.length;
        }

        resizeTable();
    });

//    var row = "#table-body tbody>tr";
    var srowCount = row.filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;

    function rowCount(srowCount) {
        if (srowCount === 0) {
            if (!row.last().hasClass('s_empty')) {
                $("#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Search not found</td></tr>');
            }
            $("tr.s_empty").show();
        } else {
            $("tr.s_empty").remove();
        }
    }

    function resizeTable() {
        //width adjustments
        $("#search-criteria").width($("div.headerwrapper").width() - 30);

        var tbody = $('#table-body');
        var thead = $('table.header');
        var tds = tbody.find('thead th');
        var ths = thead.find('th');
        tbody.width('100%');
        tds.css('width', '');
        thead.width(tbody.width());
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
            tds.eq(i).css('width', ths.eq(i).outerWidth());
        }
        tbody.width('auto');
    }
});
```

Everyone's comment and help are appreciated.

Comment: Is it a JSON data? Are you allowed to use some plugins? Like datatables?

Comment: I don’t think it is a JSON. Just pure HTML table and JavaScript with Jquery library. //If I write the plugin, yes I can use it. But no if you are suggesting external. Thanks for the datatable plugin suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does http://jsfiddle.net/b42vn2nh/97/ demonstrate your your issue? If so does http://jsfiddle.net/b42vn2nh/99/ solve your problem?

In the first link I have added a 3 second delay between render and your javascript running using

```
$(document).ready(window.setTimeout(dostuff, 3000));
```

In the second link I have added the css rules

```
#table-body {
    width:100%;
}

#table-body thead {
    height:34px;
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5;
    color:#FFF;
    width: 100%;
}
```

There is still a flash once your javascript runs as I have not replicated all the styles your javascript is adding.

So in short your javascript is not running until all content is rendered, in the case where the table is huge this will take some time. So ensure your styles are in place right from the start by including them in a css file in the `head` of your html document.

Comment: thanks David. Although I was thinking if there are other simple method aside from setTimeout. But this works too, and good note that you mention about my css ordering. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your new table to a div which is either not yet attached to the DOM or currently `style="display:none"`. Either way the user will not be able to see the table until you are done adding rows to it.

```
var div = $("<div>", {class: "tablewrapper"});
var table = $("<table>").appendTo(div);
// Add all rows to table
...
div.appendBefore(tbody)
```

or

```
var div= $("<div>", {class: "tablewrapper", style: "display:none"});
...
div.css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: I may of got the wrong end of the stick here. I thought you where fetching the data via an AJAX call and adding to the DOM after receiving the input. Looking at your code the delay may just be waiting for the table to render before firing on-load. I have added a different answer with different assumptions about your issue.